# sudo apt-get update failing inside Docker container running Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, apt, docker, container

Inside my docker container, whenever I try to execute the following command `sudo apt-get update`. It fails with the following error:

```
lab@f482bded4be2:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 26, in <module>
    col.create(db)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 94, in create
    self._fill_commands(con)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 138, in _fill_commands
    self._parse_single_commands_file(con, fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 176, in _parse_single_commands_file
    suite=tagf.section["suite"]
KeyError: 'suite'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi
E: Sub-process returned an error code`
```

I have check to make sure that `/usr/lib/cnf-update-db` exists.

I have verified that python packages exists on the system:

```
lab@f482bded4be2:~$ apt list | grep command | grep found

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

command-not-found/focal-updates 20.04.6 all [upgradable from: 20.04.4]
packagekit-command-not-found/focal-updates,focal-security 1.1.13-2ubuntu1.1 amd64
python3-commandnotfound/focal-updates 20.04.6 all [upgradable from: 20.04.4]
```

Verified that python module is installed:

```
lab@f482bded4be2:~$ pip3 list | grep command
command-not-found      0.3
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this with a fresh Ubuntu focal image (`docker run ubuntu:focal apt-get update`) which mean that you have made modifications that you are not showing. In what way does your Docker container differ from the official Ubuntu focal image?

Comment: Are dockers meant to be updated? I thought they are basically RO images with certain directories you can mark RW.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I have a container that was created based on an image that was created over a year ago.  So I would like to perform an apt-get update to see if any packages are outdated.

Comment: @Kusalananda apt-get update was used in the docker file to create the image.  So I don't understand why the it's not working inside inside the container.  I will create new image with non of my changes.  And try again